# Facebook app: fail to fetch profile information (name)

Tags: php, html, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

When i write this code>`

```
require 'facebook-api/facebook.php';

// Creating our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '143873775888888',
  'secret' => '650e5a4645f44g5s5f8edh58395a16',
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
  /*  You application logic goes here  */
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;



?>

<h3> Welcome <?php  echo $user_profile['name']; ?> !!! </h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">`
```

when i write this code, all goes right! But when i add this code ->$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET'); it gives error saying 
`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in /home/u516971380/public_html/p/php/facebook-api/base_facebook.php on line 1012`... 
i am using facebook sdk 3.2.3 (not the latest version 4). Please tell me what is the wrong in this code so that the problem occured ...

Comment: Do you log your user in? If not, that's why. If you do and for some reason excluded it from your answer, please add it. :)

Comment: yes sir, i tested this being logged in ... when i run this code,,, it shows userid , access token and profile picture correctly.. but when i try to fetch user name, first name or profile information using $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); then this error is occuring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Set Proxy To Connect Facebook.com

Find Code In base_facebook.php

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
  );
```

And Add option

```
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_PROXY      => '199.200.120.140:8089',
  );
```